# Activate animation on scroll

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I have a header, which needs to animate when user is scrolling.

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
var value = $(this).scrollTop();
if (value > 150) {
    $( "body" ).addClass( "scroll" );
    $( "header.head" ).animate({top:'-15px'}); }
else {
    $( "body" ).removeClass( "scroll" );
    $( "header.head" ).animate({top:'0px'}); }
    }
});
```

When user reaches Y = 150 the body gets a new class called ("scroll") and then the header gets a top:-15px which is animated.

My problem is that, in else if I put:

```
$( "header.head" ).animate({top:'0px'}); }
```

this simply doesn't work, in fact, the whole script stops working and can't figure out what it is.

How can I make it work?

Comment: I don't know if this is the overall issue but `animate()` has more parameters that need to be passed if you want it to actually animate.

Comment: JQuery Animate has defaults, his animate() is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An extra brace'}' was there and use `stop()` as in the below code

Try this

```
$(document).scroll(function (e) {
var value = $(this).scrollTop();
if (value > 150) {
    $( "body" ).addClass( "scroll" );
    $( "header.head" ).stop().animate({top:'-15px'}); 
 }
else {
    $( "body" ).addClass( "scroll" );
    $("header.head" ).stop().animate({top:'0px'});
 }

});
```

Hope this helps,Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error, extra `}`

```
$(document).scroll(function () {/*start anon func*/
    var value = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (value > 150) {/*start if*/
       $( "body" ).addClass( "scroll" );
       $( "header.head" ).animate({top:'-15px'}); /*end if*/}
    else {/*start else*/
       $( "body" ).removeClass( "scroll" );
       $( "header.head" ).animate({top:'0px'}); /*end else*/}
    /*end anon func*/}
/*extra brace*/});
```